# Allowing IP's to access Apache Load Balancer

Tags: httpd, rhel7, mod-balancer

Why it is not allowing my IP to access `Apache Load Balancer`

```
  <Location /balancer-manager>
   SetHandler balancer-manager
   Require host demo-002
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1 10.201.165.186
  </Location>
```

Seeing the following error

```
 [access_compat:error] [pid 22702] [client 10.201.165.86:59524] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/balancer-manager

Apache version: Apache/2.4.6
```

Please suggest .

Comment: Are you even running that configuration? The syntax isn't valid anymore. And Apache on RHEL will refuse a broken configuration and continue running with the old one, if asked to reload.

Comment: Can you please point me to the documentation link of new syntax

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

Answer (score 0):

It seems on Apache 2.4 , we have to use `Require` parameter to allow an IP address . SO for my scenario , the following below works

```
<Location /balancer-manager>
   SetHandler balancer-manager
   Require ip 127 10.201.165.86
 </Location>
```